# Record/Revert DynamoDB state for integration testing

Tags: integration-testing, amazon-dynamodb

I want to write integration testing for my API Gateway which is using DynamoDB as backend. I was wondering if there is a method/framework/libraries which provides flexibility to record DynamoDB state before tests and revert it back to original state after the tests?

Ideally, I want something which can keep track changes made in DynamoDB since the beginning of tests and revert all those changes once the test is completed.

Answer (score 1):

I use DynamoDB Local in my test environment, instead of running tests against DynamoDB directly. This saves costs and time. I use a test framework (RSpec) where I can delete anything stored in the database after a test is run.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html

If you need to run tests against a real DynamoDB table, look into DynamoDB streams + AWS Lambda. You can write a Lambda function that is triggered on item changes from your table. That function can, for example, store a record of the change in another table. Once your test is done, it can kick off a second Lambda function which goes through the change table and reverts each change in your original table.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html

Comment: adding local db wouldn't help me test my APIGatway endpoints. So this option isn't valid for me. If I had to test just the business logic then it would been a good option but not end-to-end.

Comment: Then, DynamoDB streams + AWS Lambda might be the best approach for you, to easily track changes to your table. I use this tech combination a lot for different things (not for tests) and it's pretty easy to set up.

Answer (score 0):

as readyornot recommended, i am also using DynamoDBLocal for integration test. I implemented it like with the following concept:-

1. Add DynamoDBLocal dependency in the dependency management (in my case gradle: testCompile 'com.amazonaws:DynamoDBLocal:1.11.86').
2. DynamoDBLocal server needs some native files add them to the test resources, you will find them in the extracted files of the lib (sqlite4java-win32-x86.dll, libsqlite4java-linux-i386.so...etc)
3. In the @Before Setup of the Junit class set java library path with the location of the native libs you placed in step 2.
   `SQLite.setLibraryPath("src/test/resources/location/of/native");`
4. In the setup method as well start the DynamoDB local server with inMemory mode, so you don't need to delete any records after the test finished.

   `final String[] localArgs = { "-inMemory" };
   DynamoDBProxyServer server=ServerRunner.createServerFromCommandLineArgs(localArgs);
   server.start();
   ddb = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder
           .standard()
           .withEndpointConfiguration(new    EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:8000", "local"))
           .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new    BasicAWSCredentials("test", "password")))
           .build();
   table = createTable(ddb, TABLE_NAME, HASH_KEY_NAME, SORT_KEY_NAME);`
   Create table like that

`private CreateTableResult createTable(AmazonDynamoDB ddb, String tableName, String hashKeyName,
        String sortKeyName)
    {
       List<AttributeDefinition> attributeDefinitions = new ArrayList<AttributeDefinition>();
       attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition(hashKeyName, ScalarAttributeType.S));
       attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition(sortKeyName, ScalarAttributeType.S));
       List<KeySchemaElement> ks = new ArrayList<KeySchemaElement>();
       ks.add(new KeySchemaElement(hashKeyName, KeyType.HASH));
       ks.add(new KeySchemaElement(sortKeyName, KeyType.RANGE));
       ProvisionedThroughput provisionedthroughput = new ProvisionedThroughput(1000L, 1000L);
       CreateTableRequest request =
         new CreateTableRequest()
         .withTableName(tableName)
         .withAttributeDefinitions(attributeDefinitions)
         .withKeySchema(ks)
         .withProvisionedThroughput(provisionedthroughput);
       return ddb.createTable(request);
    }`

5. And here is an example of a test method that tests the table metadata
   `@Test
   public void createTableTest()
   {
       TableDescription tableDesc = table.getTableDescription();
       assertEquals(TABLE_NAME, tableDesc.getTableName());
       assertEquals("[{AttributeName: "
           + HASH_KEY_NAME
           + ",KeyType: HASH}, {AttributeName: "
           + SORT_KEY_NAME
           + ",KeyType: RANGE}]",
                       tableDesc.getKeySchema().toString());
       assertEquals("[{AttributeName: "
           + HASH_KEY_NAME
           + ",AttributeType: S}, {AttributeName: "
           + SORT_KEY_NAME
           + ",AttributeType: S}]", tableDesc.getAttributeDefinitions().toString());
       assertEquals(Long.valueOf(1000L), tableDesc.getProvisionedThroughput().getReadCapacityUnits());
       assertEquals(Long.valueOf(1000L), tableDesc.getProvisionedThroughput().getWriteCapacityUnits());
       assertEquals("ACTIVE", tableDesc.getTableStatus());
       assertEquals("arn:aws:dynamodb:ddblocal:000000000000:table/" + TABLE_NAME, tableDesc.getTableArn());
       ListTablesResult tables = ddb.listTables();
       assertEquals(1, tables.getTableNames().size());
   }`

   6. implement @After method so it deletes the table and shutdown the server

   `@After
   public void tearDown()
   {
       ddb.deleteTable(TABLE_NAME);
       ddb.shutdown();
   }`